# LabVIEW: IMAQ colorImage to Array

Tags: arrays, labview

[image]I'm working on an application where an image should be read from LabVIEW (by a camera) and preprocessed in python function (the Image should not be read from a file path, meaning we should not save the image shown in the camera but it should be read directly in the python function and that's why I thought of sending its pixels values to the function), for this I'm using system exec.

as a first step I was trying to read an Image from a file path to check if I can have its pixels values as an array and send it to the command line. I used the IMAQ colorImage to array and to convert it to a string  I used "Flatten to string function" (since there's no 32U to string function)  but as shown in the picture I'm getting strange symbols.
Ps: I used system exec because I don't have the license for the other python LabVIEW connectivity

Please if you know how can I have the array of the image pixels to send it as an argument to the python function help me, I will be so grateful!

[image]

The new block Diagram :
[image]

Comment: what is expected data format of your Python script? could you give us a short example? is it something like "python one_single_image.py --matrice 535353,3253225,25625325,235252,... ?

Comment: @MateuszOwczarek yes ! but all between barckets smth like [(124, 95, 78), (124, 100, 81), (124, 109, 83), (127, 113, 85), (129, 112, 86)], but now I figured out another problem is that in the python function there will be a resize function (     image = cv2.resize(image, (128, 128)) so when I tried entering the matrix of a random image manually in the code I got an openCV error: (-215:Assertion failed).. so I don't know if this will even work if I can have the right data from Labview.. if u know wht I mean..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** use the *flatten to string* node to send the image data to your python script but you should note the following things:

The image data will be converted from a U32 2D-array to unsigned bytes (values 0-255). Some of these values are outside the standard ASCII character set, so they will not render correctly (they look like weird symbols or blank spaces). This also means that it is difficult to pass them as arguments but we can write them to *stdin*.

The *flatten to string* node (by default) appends the array size as I32s to the beginning of the data (which is useful) and uses the *big-endian format* (which is not).

The up-shot of this is that we need to override the default behaviour of the *flatten to string* node to use the little-endian format and strip off the first 8-bytes to convert to the array width and height in python.

LabVIEW stores image pixels in ARGB order but as we have flattened using the little-endian option, we end up with data in BGRA order which is conviently the expected channel order for openCV.

Putting this together and making sure we pass the image data into the `standard input` input of the *system exec.vi* we have the following LabVIEW and python code (Python Version *3.10.4*):

[image: LabVIEW Code to pass image to python via standard-input]

```py
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read std in as byteArray
dataInBuffer = sys.stdin.buffer.read()

# first 8 bytes are two, 4-byte signed integer values image width and height
width = int.from_bytes( dataInBuffer[0:3], "little", signed=True )
height = int.from_bytes( dataInBuffer[4:7], "little", signed=True)

# the rest of the data is 4-channel pixel data in BGRA format
imageBuffer = np.frombuffer(dataInBuffer[8:], dtype=np.uint8)

image = imageBuffer.reshape(width,height,4)

cv2.imshow('sample image',image)

cv2.waitKey(0) # waits until a key is pressed
cv2.destroyAllWindows() # destroys the window showing image
```

In response to the comment from @Asky

Sending images back to LabVIEW is indeed possible using the `sys.stdout.buffer.write` function.

Assuming that we want to use the *Unflatten from string* node in LabVIEW and we still have 4-channel BGRA data then the code is quite straight forward. We write the output image width and height as 4-byte signed integers first and then the image data. If you no longer have 4-channel data you could pad the data in python with zeros or do the padding in LabVIEW

The python code for these two cases is

```py
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read std in as byteArray
dataInBuffer = sys.stdin.buffer.read()

# first 8 bytes are two, 4-byte signed integer values image width and height
width = int.from_bytes( dataInBuffer[0:3], "little", signed=True )
height = int.from_bytes( dataInBuffer[4:7], "little", signed=True)

# the rest of the data is 4-channel pixel data in BGRA format
imageBuffer = np.frombuffer(dataInBuffer[8:], dtype=np.uint8)

image = imageBuffer.reshape(width,height,4)

# process image
image = cv2.putText(image, 'Greetings from Python', (20,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
                   0.5, (255,0,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

outputWidthBytes = width.to_bytes(4,'little',signed=True)
outputHeightBytes = height.to_bytes(4,'little',signed=True)

# write to standard out
sys.stdout.buffer.write(outputWidthBytes)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(outputHeightBytes)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(image)

# write out three channel example
bgrImage = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)

# write to standard out as 3D array (width x height x channels)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(outputWidthBytes)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(outputHeightBytes)
sys.stdout.buffer.write((3).to_bytes(4,'little',signed=True))
sys.stdout.buffer.write(bgrImage)

# use flush to ensure all bytes are written to stdout before the program exits
sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
```

And the LabVIEW code extended to process the `stdout` data becomes

[image: LabVIEW Code to send and recieve images from Python via stdin and stdout]

Comment: Thank you so much !I didn't really know how to deal with stdin before now, this is very helpful ! so I assume that I can display  photos created by a python file to an image indicator on Labview  by using sys.stdout.buffer.write? instead of saving these images in a folder and then reading them..?

Comment: @Asky - indeed, check the update

Comment: I appreciate your effort ! but I'm having an error  with  the "unflatten from string" function, you can find the updated block diagram in the post

Comment: Ensure that you are writing the array size in python before the image data and that the array types you add into the unflatten from string have the correct numeric types (U32 for the 2D array and U8 for the 3D array). Wiring your error wires through will help you see what errors are occurring. If you are still stuck, select the VIs on the block diagram and select "Edit>>Create VI Snippet From Selection" and upload that to your question. It would also help to see your updated python code

Comment: Also I am using Python Version Python 3.10.4

Comment: the problem was that I didn't put the correct numeric type for the 3D array, thank you a million :) !

Answer (score 1):

Check this example to convert numeric data table into string formatted as you want: [image: example]

Comment: Thank you so much ! it did give me the data as a string,I will accept your comment as the answer !  but I have another question about the IMaQ ColorimagetoArray function, if you have an idea.. actually the image pixels (the data) are stated as ((1139273)  (1109271) (1089067) etcc..) I mean in each colomn when it should be stated as ( (113 92 73)  (110 92 71) (108 90 67) ) so it could be seperated by comma and printed as [(113, 92, 73), (110, 92, 71), (108, 90, 67)] as it is printed when I get the data of the image in python since it is an RGB image

Comment: So my question is , is there another way to convert an image to an array to get the data as it is supposed to be? or are the two shapes of data ( I mean [(1139273), (1109271), (1089067)] aand [(113, 92, 73), (110, 92, 71), (108, 90, 67)] ) the same?   I'm sure it is about the ImaQ colorImage to Array  not about how I concatenate and print it

Comment: you can use https://documentation.help/NI-Vision-LabView/IMAQ_IntegerToColorValue.html function to decode this big numbers into cluster of RGB values